# Is it bad to call (Transaction) .replace(newFragment) within Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok, I know it kinda silly question. Forgive me I'm very new to Android.

The question is simple as the title. Is it bad to call replace fragment within fragment?

IIRC suggests that fragment should never communicate with another directly. So the question is i just ask has anything related to it?

Sample code:

```
...somewhere in Fragment1 class
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction
     .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment2());
```

I didn't have problem with it. Just curious if it has a bad affect.

Thanks. sorry for my bad ENG.

Comment: Within my team (fairly large app) we hold ourselves to a hard and fast rule that only the enclosing Activity should manipulate its Fragments. If a fragment triggers another fragment (e.g. master -> detail), this is implemented with a callback to the Activity, and the Activity makes the UI change. This helps us understand the code, you get more of a hierarchical approach to who-triggers-what instead of a spaghetti weave.

Comment: and if Fragment1 need to show the details of its in Fragment1.2   .
Is it reasonable to call replace() in Fragment1
because only Fragment1 can trigger Fragment1.2 not Fragment2,3,4,...?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a problem at all. You will be doing it a lot.
It's even possible to have an application with just one Activity that holds a container and a menu. You can load different fragments in the container by clicking the menu, but maybe you have a fragment with a list of things and clicking the list let's you go to the details of that. That could be a fragment too.

Activity holds fragment with a list of things >> click thing >> go to detail fragment.

That way you asked the first fragment to open the second one, which is no problem at all.